# Error while executing Exchange powershell commands from C# program

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2010

I tried the following code to get the mailbox from an exchange server.I am encountering issue while running the program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string user = "Domain\\username";
   SecureString passwd = new SecureString();
   foreach (char c in "Password")
   {
        passwd.AppendChar(c);
   }
   PSCredential cred = new PSCredential(user, passwd);
   WSManConnectionInfo ConnInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(liveIdconnectionUri), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", cred);
   ConnInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
   ConnInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 2;
   //ConnInfo.ProxyAccessType = System.Management.Automation.Remoting.ProxyAccessType.AutoDetect;
   Runspace ExchangeRunspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ConnInfo);
   PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
   PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
   command.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox");
   command.AddParameter("Identity", user);
   powershell.Commands = command;
   // open the remote runspace
   ExchangeRunspace.Open();
   // associate the runspace with powershell
   powershell.Runspace = ExchangeRunspace;
   // invoke the powershell to obtain the results
   powershell.Invoke();
   Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

   foreach (PSObject obj in results)
   {
        PSMemberInfoCollection<PSPropertyInfo> propInfos = obj.Properties;
        Console.WriteLine("********************");
        foreach (PSPropertyInfo propInfo in propInfos)
        {
            string propInfoValue = (propInfo.Value == null) ? "" : propInfo.Value.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", propInfo.Name, propInfoValue);
        }


    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I get the following error while running the above code

```
Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.  
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic."
```

Even when I run the command 'New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $liveIdconnectionUri -credential "user@example.com" -authentication kerberos', I get the same error.

Any pointer to solve this would be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to the system it would be hard to give you an exact cause. Some things I would try:

*** Ensure you have remoting set up correctly and that WSMAN exceptions are present in the firewall. Try running "winrm quickconfig".

*** Ensure that you have setup the correct remote script execution policy for the server. See (Get/Set)-ExecutionPolicy

*** Make sure the proper domain credentials are being passed and that it can be authenticated from the target computer to the domain ctrlr.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string username = "Hitesh";
            string password = "Shrimali";
            string sSAMAccount = "SAMAccountName"; //here Also you can use Your emailAddress

            var lyncPW = GetSecurePassword(password);

            PSCredential creds = new PSCredential(username, lyncPW);
            Runspace m_RunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            m_RunSpace.Open();


            PSCommand CmdCredential = new PSCommand();
            CmdCredential.AddCommand("Get-Credential");
            CmdCredential.AddParameter("Credential", creds);
            powershell.Commands = CmdCredential;
            powershell.Runspace = m_RunSpace;
            powershell.Invoke();


            PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
            command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
            command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", "YourURL/PowerShell/"); //Your Exchange URL
            command.AddParameter("Credential", creds);
            command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Default");
            powershell.Commands = command;
            powershell.Runspace = m_RunSpace;
            powershell.Invoke();


            PSSessionOption sessionOption = new PSSessionOption();
            sessionOption.SkipCACheck = true;
            sessionOption.SkipCNCheck = true;
            sessionOption.SkipRevocationCheck = true;
            command.AddParameter("SessionOption", sessionOption);
            powershell.Commands = command;
            powershell.Runspace = m_RunSpace;

            Collection<PSSession> result = powershell.Invoke<PSSession>();
            PSSession ps = result.FirstOrDefault();

            RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(m_RunSpace);
            runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser");


            PSCommand cmdImportSession = new PSCommand();
            cmdImportSession.AddCommand("Import-PSSession");
            cmdImportSession.AddParameter("Session", ps);
            cmdImportSession.AddParameter("AllowClobber", true);
            powershell.Commands = cmdImportSession;
            powershell.Runspace = m_RunSpace;
            powershell.Invoke();


            PSCommand cmdNewMoveRequest = new PSCommand();
            cmdNewMoveRequest.AddCommand("New-MoveRequest");
            cmdNewMoveRequest.AddParameter("Identity", sSAMAccount);
            cmdNewMoveRequest.AddParameter("TargetDatabase", "BoxerProperty Disabled Users Mailbox Database");
            powershell.Commands = cmdNewMoveRequest;
            powershell.Runspace = m_RunSpace;
            powershell.Invoke();


            foreach (ErrorRecord current in powershell.Streams.Error)
            {
                // log errors
            }

            m_RunSpace.Close();
```

Comment: I have used "New-MoveRequest"  same as you can use any command here. - thanks -Hitesh shrimali